# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found

Tags: 8, installation, composer

I have installed the [EntityPrint](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print) module in drupal 8 for the pdf conversion.

Followed below procedure:

> `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8`
>
> Run: `composer require "drupal/entity_print 2.x"` in the site `docroot/`.

1. https://packagist.org/packages/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf
2. https://packagist.org/packages/dompdf/dompdf
3. https://packagist.org/packages/tecnickcom/tcpdf

I have installed the above packages using, as the entity print module insisted to install it in drupal page.

Once the installation was done, drupal site was crashed, while checking the error log, I got the following:

[image: FastCGI error: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found]

> [error] FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /var/www/html/drupal/index.php on line 16" while reading response header from upstream

I have uninstalled the packages but unable to disable entity print. Since my `drush` command results in error.

Can anyone please help me to find out?

Comment: Do you have a backup of your db and your code in version control?  If not, you should re-consider the way you are managing your code/db; it's a lot easier to roll back your code and db to the last known good state than to debug a botched uninstallation.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

- Check if `autoload.php` file exists and it includes the right path to your `vendor/` folder.
- Clear any external cache services if in use (e.g. *Memcached* or *Redis*).
- If you're using PHP 5.x, you should use PHP 7.x instead.

---

To rebuild your site from scratch based on your `composer.json` file, try the following steps:

1. Backup and delete the `/core` and `/vendor` directories completely.
2. Delete the `composer.lock` file.
3. Run: `composer install`.
4. Run: `composer update`.

Source: [D8 conflict resolution](https://www.drupal.org/node/2886985#comment-12132933).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you installed your site using composer but I suspect Symphony is missing or your vendor directory is missing.  Check if you have drupal inside composer.json file. If you do see Drupal I would recommend the following:

1. Make a backup of your entire code just in case you need to go back. (Hopefull you are using Git so you don't need to do this)
2. In the root of your project remove the vendor directory
3. run `composer install`
4. run `drush cr`

It should download Drupal and all the symphony components.