# DrupalKernel' not found after server migration

Tags: migrations

i am try to migrate a drupal site to a new server (from cPanel to Plesk).

1. I copyied the files from old server and pasted on new server
2. Export database via phpmyadmin and import on new database on new server, again via phpmyadmin.
3. Edit settings.php (on /httpdocs/sites/default/settings.php) with new credentials for database connection on new server.

and i have the error:

Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../../public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 478

Warning: include(/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../../public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 478

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/composer/../../public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/opt/plesk/php/7.2/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 478

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/domain.gr/httpdocs/index.php on line 16** (Line:16 in index.php : $kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);)

The two server are running on same php version 7.2 with nginx.
Composer is allready installer on plesk v2.2.6

I tried to apply this solutions:
[PHP Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247407/php-fatal-error-class-drupal-core-drupalkernel-not-found)

and others similar solutions, by updating composer (by running composer install, composer update) , with no reasults.

I have root access only in new server (we are the web-hosters) and we shouldered the site migration.

Did i miss something? Any help, will be nice.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`. If that fails, restart PHP-FPM

Comment: Yes and thnx for your reply, but, i will run this command via SSH, in which directory i will run this command? on hosting packet root  or on server root?

Comment: on Server root and host packate root same reasults:# composer dump-autoload
/usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory